# How to properly pair two users with Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to do a chat where guys gets paired with girls and girls gets paired with guys.

I'm using Firebase to handle the backend. As soon as the user enters the page, he is assigned to a database named "searching". This is what i got for the pairing:

```
this.ref = firebase.database().ref("searching").orderByChild("sex").equalTo(this.lookingFor).limitToFirst(1).on("child_added", (snap) => { 
this.pairedUserUid = snap.val().uid; //Matches the users
firebase.database().ref("searching").child(snap.val().uid).remove(); //Remove user from searching database
}
```

If there is only one person looking it works. The problem is when two users are searching for the same thing. For example:

User X is a guy looking for users that are girls; 
User Y is also a guy looking for users that are girls;

User Z enters app, is a girl and is looking for users that are guys.

User X and Y both gets paired with Z!
What i REALLY want is only one of them (X or Y) to get paired with Z while the other keeps waiting.

How can i accomplish this?

Comment: Think the other way: don't actively waiting, but passively waiting - not X and Y gets paired with Z but Z find pair either X or Y. (Hope that helps)

Comment: But it's the same code for either X,Y and Z

Comment: I mean: the former one just register in the database, and waiting for selection from latter users.

Comment: Yes you always have a racing condition. I think you need a firebase Function for this to handle the matching. Then when a user is assigned to the "searching" table, it triggers an OnCreate event and you could do some matching logic. Then, maybe each user could have under their userID a node which is "matches" and frontend can listen to this node for updates so once you have a match you can do something on the frontend. Just brainstorming a bit xD

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, they really helped me out! I've put the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved it:

I changed "on" to "once". This way, the database will be consulted only once after the user logs in. If found, register the chat in the databse of both this user and the other:

```
this.ref = firebase.database().ref("searching").orderByChild("sex").equalTo(this.lookingFor).limitToFirst(1).once("child_added", (snap) => { 

    //Matches the users
     this.pairedUserUid = snap.val().uid; 

  //Register the chat to the user database
 this.ref1 = firebase.database().ref("users").child(this.AngularFireAuth.auth.currentUser.uid).child("chats").push({ 
   otherUserUid: this.otherUserUid,
 });

   //Register the chat to the other user database
 this.ref1 = firebase.database().ref("users").child(this.otherUserUid).child("chats").push({ 
   otherUserUid: this.auth.currentUser.uid,
 });

//Remove user from searching database
firebase.database().ref("searching").child(snap.val().uid).remove(); 
});
```

If not found, the user gets "passive" listening to changes in his chat database (this time using "on"):

```
this.ref1 = firebase.database().ref("users").child(this.AngularFireAuth.auth.currentUser.uid).child("chats").on("child_added", (snap) => {
//Matches the users
this.otherUserUid = snap.val().otherUserUid;
});
```

Comment: I think you will still have a problem if the two users X and Y enter at the same time. They can still be connected to the same person Z before this person is removed from the "searching" database.

Comment: yes i realised that later... but how can i get a different treatment for two users that enters at the same time and is searching for the same thing using the same code for both?

Comment: i just found out the firebase TRANSACTION feature, that solved my problem: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write